# I'm having problem trying to create a Page Guard for a variable

Tags: c++, variables, memory

I'm using this code to protect a variable address using page guard, and I get the exception when I try to access the variable(Good), but I'm getting the exception when I don't even try to access the variable. (Is this normal??)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>


    int main()
    {
        DWORD oldp;
        DWORD* pdp = new DWORD;
        *pdp = 0;
        if (!VirtualProtect(pdp, sizeof(DWORD), PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldp))
            return 1;

        // *pdp = 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

It is the exception that is getting raised.

Unhandled exception at 0x77E4BAAC (ntdll.dll) in Project2.exe: 0x80000001: Not implemented (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x01696608).

Comment: Much easier and better alternative: enable *Address Sanitizer*, that is now embedded in all major compilers, including MSVC.

Comment: Or use _PageHeap_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags-and-pageheap

Answer (score 1):

Setting page protections works for the *whole page* (normally 4k, maybe 16k or even 2MB). Your code as written currently has no way to ensure that *only* the variable you care about is the only thing on that page. Modern heaps make sure that lots of allocations are packed together on a single page, else it would be horribly inefficient.

You need to replace your allocation code (`new DWORD;`) with manual use of VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree/etc. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Memory/reserving-and-committing-memory.

If you do this you control what is on the page you protect, and can ensure that it is exactly what you want.